# Reference request: measure induced by a distribution.

Tags: measure-theory, reference-request, distribution-theory

I am looking for a reference that explains the connection between a measure $\mu$ and a distribution as described for instance [here](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GeneralizedFunction.html):

$$\langle F,g\rangle =\int_{\Omega} g  \;d\mu$$

where $g$ is some test function and $\langle.,.\rangle$ denotes the bilinear pairing between distributions and test functions.
I tried looking inside the **humongous** 5 volumes book by Gel'fand and Shilov but I wasn't able to find anything (although I am sure it must be there, somewhere).

So if you know where I can find this I would be glad!
Thanks in advance.

Comment: what is a test function on a probability space ?

Comment: @Surb  for instance if $\Omega$ is the real line, then the test functions could be the Schwarz space

Comment: Look on “Analysis” of Lieb and Loss, Theorem 6.22.

Comment: thanks @GiuseppeNegro, this was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

Uhm... Measures induce distributions, but not the other way around. If you're working on a nice-enough space, measures represent the dual of the space of continuous functions (that are zero at infinity), but distributions represent the dual of the smooth functions (that are zero at infinity)... Or Schwartz functions... Anyway, since you can "do more" with smooth functions (like: differentiate and evaluate), there are "more" distributions than measures.

Comment: indeed I wanted to say the other way around, but do you know where I can find a reference these things ?

Comment: That measures are the dual space of continuous functions (that vanish at infinity) is called the Riesz-Markov representation theorem and can for example be found in Rudin: Real and Complex Analysis, chapter 4(?), and the statement about distributions is just the definition (don't know that much about distributions, either), so I'd guess a book on distributions. Maybe a slightly advanced functional analysis book, idk.